# Why can't I call an exception after I except it?

Tags: python, exception, scope

Why can't I raise an Exception instance after I catch that Exception class? Oddly enough, I run into this error when I run the script from a function but not when ran directly in the python shell.

```
In [2]: def do():
   ...:     try:
   ...:         raise ValueError('yofoo')
   ...:     except TypeError, ValueError:
   ...:         raise ValueError('yo')
   ...: 

In [3]: do()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-30c46b84d9a4> in <module>()
----> 1 do()

<ipython-input-2-b62158d6343b> in do()
      1 def do():
      2     try:
----> 3         raise ValueError('yofoo')
      4     except TypeError, ValueError:
      5         raise ValueError('yo')

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ValueError' referenced before assignment
```

Expected error here:

```
In [3]: try:
   ...:     raise ValueError("foo")
   ...: except ValueError:
   ...:     raise ValueError("bar")
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d5c83419a5ea> in <module>()
      2     raise ValueError("foo")
      3 except ValueError:
----> 4     raise ValueError("bar")
      5 

ValueError: bar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
except TypeError, ValueError:
```

should be

```
except (TypeError, ValueError):
```

When you use `except TypeError, ValueError:`, you are assigning the Exception instance to the variable name `ValueError`.

With your current code, when Python parses the `do` function, it notes `ValueError` is a local variable because `except TypeError, ValueError:` assigns a value to `ValueError`. But when you reference it in the first `try-suite`, with `raise ValueError('yofoo')`, the local variable `ValueError` has no value. So you get `UnboundLocalError`.

---

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
... except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
...     pass
```

> Note that the parentheses around this tuple are required, because
>   except ValueError, e: was the syntax used for what is normally written
>   as except ValueError as e: in modern Python (described below). The old
>   syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility. This means
>   except RuntimeError, TypeError is not equivalent to except
>   (RuntimeError, TypeError): but to except RuntimeError as TypeError:
>   which is not what you want.